# how to create new MSSQL user with all privilegs only to ONE database

Tags: sql-server

I've been trying to figure out how to add a new user,
but I haven't managed to figure it out so the new user will have access to only a specific database without being able to see the whole server / users / databases.
Any help will be apperciated

thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? It is a matter of running `CREATE USER xxx ....` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) and `GRANT yyy ...` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-database-permissions-transact-sql)

Comment: A user is a database object. Are you talking about a Login? Also, are you talking asking how to stop the Login seeing other objects in the object explorer? You can stop this, however, it will also "hide" objects they are have access to, as well as those they don't.

Comment: Hello, i do not have any experience with SQL server , i've already tried few times with different commands / tried from the GUI itself but i ended up with a user without any access to databases / user that can see all the users / databases. can you be more specific?

Comment: You do have the command `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [Login];`. Unsurprising, this denies a **Login** (not a User, these are different) to see any databases (apart from `master` and `tempdb`). They can still access any databases that they previously had access to via a mapped user, but won't be able to see those databases in SSMS's object explorer or in `sys.databases`.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new user who have access to only 1 database, you need to create a new login and add a user mapping to that login for the database you want,

to do this, open MSSQL Management Studio, on the left panel, expand your server by click on the checkbox and select security then Logins.
Then, right click on the logins box and select new login.
On the new login window, provide login name(user name) and authentication type, then there's select page tab on the left side, then select user mapping and add the database you want to that user, also remember to add object to default schema of that database.

[image]

Comment: I feel this is a bit misleading. What you're doing there is creating a login and a user, mapping that User to the Login. The fact that the Dialogue Window says **"Login - New"** is a bit of a hint. ;)

Comment: yeah, it creates new login for the user. the question is how to give access to 1 db to user, so, this will do that, if not I'm missing something

Comment: That would create a User for the Login on the Database Model, yes, without any mapped permissions; so could do `USE model;` and that's about it. The OP does, however, state they want to make the Login/User "without being able to see the whole server / users / databases". They'd still be able to "see" all the other objects in the `sys` tables, just be unable to access to them. For example, they wouldn't be able to do `USE AdventureWorks2012;`, as they don't have a mapped user.

Comment: I don get your point. the one creating this user should be obviously the admin. But the created user or login can only access the db mapped to him.
I'm a bit confused, what is your point ?

Comment: Log in to your newly created Login. You'll visually see all your other databases in Object Explorer, even though you don't have access them. Try `SELECT [name] FROM sys.databases;`. Again, you'll get a full list of databases, even though the Login doedn't have access to those other database. it depends what the OP's definition of "see" is. If they mean "access" they have used the wrong word; there are many things in life you can "see" that you can't "access". Such as when you're in a bank, you can "see" the safe behind the counter, but you can't "access" it.

Answer (score 0):

USE Databasename ;

CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD='**passwd**';

GRANT ALL ON Databasename TO username;

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2012 and higher, [Contained Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases) is what you are looking for.

Making a database **contained**, you give it the ability to authenticate a **user** (not login), and the users of contained database will see nothing at the server level, no other databases will be visible to them.